# jQuery: Rewriting Anonymous Callback to a Named Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, anonymous-function

If I do this:

```
$('h1').slideUp('slow', function() { $('div:first').fadeOut(); });
```

h1 will slide up, then the first div will fade out.

However, if I do this:

```
function last() { $('div:first').fadeOut(); }

$('h1').slideUp('slow', last());
```

h1 will slide up and div will fade out at the same time!

How can I make my second example work the same as the first one, where fadeOut() is called AFTER slideUp()?

Comment: `last !== last()`, function vs calling the function.

Comment: elclanrs, can you please explain? I don't understand what the difference is.

Comment: `slideUp` expects a function. `last` is a function. `last()` calls the function `last`. Not the same thing.

Comment: You need to reference the variable containing the function, you don't want to call the function and return whatever it returns. Adding the parenthesis in the second example would be like writing `$('h1').slideUp(function() { $('div:first').fadeOut(); }());`, note the extra parenthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the function return value (which you get by calling the function), but the function body:

```
$('h1').slideUp('slow', last);
```

---

What you did is the same as this:

```
var returned = last();             // call to last returns undefined
                                   // so returned has the value undefined
$('h1').slideUp('slow', returned); // simply sending undefined as a callback
```

So you were just executing the `last` function inline, and then passing the return value (which is `undefined` since it returns nothing) as a parameter to the `slideUp`'s callback function.

---

Hope this example will help you understand:

```js
function outer() {
  function inner() {};
  return inner;
}

alert(outer);    // returns the outer function body
alert(outer());  // returns the outer function's return value, which is the inner function
```

Comment: So JavaScript works differently than PHP? Since in PHP, whenever I need to call a function I have to use the parenthesis.

Comment: No, it's not about that - you don't need to call the function, the `slideUp` will call it when needed. Look at your original code: `function() { $('div:first').fadeOut(); }` you're not calling this function, right? It's the same in PHP.

Comment: I added an example to help you understand better.

Comment: Thanks for the example code snippet, Shomz. It helped me understand how JavaScript works.