# Button Creation, Event Handlers, Issues

Tags: jquery, button, jquery-events

Its been a while since I've used Javascript or jQuery, so I'm sure I made a stupid mistake here, but I can't figure out what I did wrong. One of my JS functions seems to run when the page loads, but doesn't when I want it to (when a button is clicked).

I am trying to pull information from a database. I am attempting to test the API written in PHP, and so I created a "test" page. There are other data fields on the page, but they all work fine. I created a JS file for the page, right now with 3 functions:

A "document.ready" function:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $( "#show_users" ).click(ShowUsers);
    $(".log_btn" ).click( ShowBSLogs(this.id));
});
```

With event handlers, the first for a single button which is in the html, and the second for a set of buttons which are dynamically created.

Each of these events should trigger one of the other two functions:

```
function ShowUsers() {
    $.post( "show", function(data,status){
        console.log(data[0]);
        $( "#output" ).empty().append( "<table id='user_table' width='100' border-color='black'><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Logs</th></tr></table>" );
        data.forEach(function(user) {
            $( "#user_table" ).append( "<tr><td>" + user.first_name + "</td><td> " + user.last_name + "</td><td> " + user.email + "</td><td><button class='log_btn' id=' "+user.u_id+" '>Logs</button></td></tr>");
        });
    
    });
}
```

and

```
function ShowBSLogs(u_id) {
    $.post( "show/uid", {id: u_id}, function(data,status){
        console.log(data);
        console.log("fired");
    });
}
```

When the page loads, `ShowBSLogs` is called, and since it isn't being passed a variable, it causes an error. When I click the original button and `ShowUsers` is called, it runs fine, and I get a table with first and last name, email, and a button with an id that is associated with the user, but when I click that button, `ShowBSLogs` isn't called.

I'd be happy to post more code from other files, but I'm fairly certain that the error is in here. Let me know if you need anything else.

Anyone?

Comment: You managed to ask the same question as the one asked two minutes before you -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268338/jquery-rewriting-anonymous-callback-to-a-named-function

Comment: @adeneo wait... I don't see it. In your question you tried to pass the return value of one function (which didn't return anything) into another function.

I'm not passing any values except this.id which is an attribute of the button. And the bigger issue is that the function is being called at document load time, not that I'm not passing the right value.

Comment: Well, I'll help you out! You can't use parentheses .... add anonymous function ................... `$(".log_btn" ).click( function() { ShowBSLogs(this.id); });`

Comment: That solved the misfiring, but it still doesn't run the function when I click a button... Thanks for a step in the right direction though!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work around this problem by creating a button object and then appending that to the table row, THEN I set the event handler(.click). I'm not sure why this works since I tried many different variations on this eventual solution and none worked, but I'm posting my solution in case it helps someone else.

test.js:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $( "#show_users" ).click( function() { ShowUsers();         });
    $( ".log_btn"    ).click( function() { ShowBSLogs(this.id); });
});


function ShowUsers() {
    $.post( "show", function(data,status){
        console.log(data[0]);
        $( "#output" ).empty().append( "<table id='user_table' width='100' border-color='black'><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Logs</th></tr></table>" );
        data.forEach(function(user) {
            var row = $(" <tr><td>" + user.first_name + "</td><td> " + user.last_name + "</td><td> " + user.email + "</td></tr>");
            var button = $('<button/>', {
                text: 'Logs',
                class: 'log_btn',
                id: user.u_id });
            row.append(button);
            $( "#user_table" ).append(row );
        });
        $( ".log_btn" ).click( function() { ShowBSLogs(this.id); }); //set event handler

    });
}


function ShowBSLogs(u_id) {
    console.log(u_id);
    $.post( "show/uid", {id: u_id}, function(data,status){
        console.log(data);
        console.log("fired");
    });
}
```